# Implementing starred favouriting system with Backbone and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to add favouriting to an app I'm building.

The basic setup involves users who have a collection of "concepts". They can suggest new concepts into the collection by submitting a text field.

Users can also "favourite" concepts by clicking a little star, exactly the way you would in Gmail or a million other apps. Favourited concepts should stick to the top of the concepts collection causing newly created concepts to appear below them.

To favourite a concept, I must POST the concept's id to `"/favourites"`.

```
class ConceptView extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'click .empty-star' : 'favourite'

  favourite: ->
    @model.favourite()

class Concept extends Backbone.Model
  favourite: ->
    $.post("/favourites", { concept_id: @id }, "json")
```

My question is about how to manage the favourited and non-favourited concepts on the client-side.

Should I have two separate collections, one for favourited concepts and another for non-favourited concepts or should I try to stick to one collection?

If I was to have a `Concept` model in a `FavouritedConcepts` collection

```
class FavouritedConcepts extends Backbone.Collection
  url: "/favourited_concetpts"
  model: Concept
```

then I can list concepts via that collection just fine because it is natural for favourited_concepts#index to scope concepts to only those that are favourited.

However, concepts are destroyed by the `ConceptsController` at `"/concepts"` and if I try to call Backbone's `model.destroy()` on a `Concept` which resides in the `FavouritedConcepts` collection then it will mistakenly send a `DELETE` request to `"/favourited_concepts"`.

The solution might be to stick to just one concepts collection, mash a `favourite` boolean attribute onto each concept and define a comparator to force favourited concepts to stick to the top of the list. However, I feel like I will lose some flexibility in my view layer by doing this. I can't have views which listen for events from a `FavouritedConceps` collection.

What is the best approach to take when implementing this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with one collection with a boolean flag for favouring. That will save you all the housekeeping to ensure proper state between the collections.

You can still implement listeners in the view that is bound to events from Concepts, you'll just need to do a concept.favourite check in callback.

Comment: This is what I chose to do in the end.